# php array manipulation to reduce redundancy

Tags: php, arrays, redundancy

an array is loaded from the database, it looks like this:

```
array=>(
  0=>array(
    'id'=>1,
    'user'=>'eric',
    'text'=>'hello'
  ),
  1=>array(
    'id'=>1,
    'user'=>'eric',
     'text'=>'how are you?'
  ),
  2=>array(
    'id'=>2,
    'user'=>'john',
     'text'=>'nice to meet you'
  ),
  ......
)
```

as you can see, the only difference within the array is the 'text' field, so I want to make another array to reduce redundancy, something like this:

```
array=>(
  0=>array(
   'id'=>1,
   'user'=>'eric',
   'text'=>array(
      0=>'hello',
      1=>'how are you?'
   )
 ),
  1=>array(
   'id'=>2,
   'user'=>'john',
   'text'=>array(
      0=>'nice to meet you',
   )
 ),
 ......
)
```

I am a new in programming, I have spent hours trying to figure it out but I can't. how can I achieve this? please help.

Comment: You can do it with only one loop

Comment: what is the specific reason you want to do this? Most reasons I can think of (speed, efficency etc) don't seem good reasons to want to do this, and if you need this structure for something, wouldn't it be smarter to just retrieve it from your database like that?

Comment: the reason is to try to avoid redundancy, as you can see the id field is redundant. But as you suggest, it will be nice to retrieve it from database like that, but how? could you show me the example code, I am using mysql.

Comment: sorry, I have changed my question a bit, making it a bit more complicated, as you can see, the only difference of each set is text, the id and user is redundant, how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

**Code :**

```
<?php
     $newarray = array();

     foreach ($array as $item)
     {
          if (!isset($newarray[$item['id']])) $newarray[$item['id']] = array();

          $newarray[$item['id']][] = $item['text'];
     }
?>
```

That will create some thing like this :

```
array (
   1 => array ("hello", "how are you?"),
   2 => array ("a","b"),
   ...
)

// where the array keys (1,2,...) will be the IDs
```

Answer (score 1):

Array keys will be `id` value

```
$new_array = array();
foreach($old_array as $value) {
    $new_array[$value['id']]['text'][] = $value['text'];
}
print_r($new_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

To make it even more compact, how about this:

```
$new_array = array();
foreach ($old_array as $item) {
    $id = $item['id'];
    if (empty($new_array[$id]) || !in_array($item['text'], $new_array[$id])) {
        $new_array[$id][] = $item['text'];
    }
}
```

This will reduce duplicit texts for given id as well.